Is it possible to send data to my PC from the SWDIO pin of an STM32F030K6T6 microcontroller?
I am creating a custom STM32F030K6T6 pcb board. I didn't think about this initially before buying all the parts and PCB board, but I need to be able to send data to my PC so I can debug print in my code. Now I have all the parts soldered onto my board and I am stuck wondering how I can print to my console.
I have easy access to 1 UART tx pin, NRST, SWDIO, and SWCLK pins. I also bought the basic st linker v2 chinese programmer that can be seen at this link here.
I am thinking it makes sense that I could connect my st linker v2 to my power, GND, and SWDIO pin and then connect this to my computer to transmit data to my PC using the SWDIO pin... But I am unsure if this can actually be acheived.
I also considered connecting power, and GND pins and then connecting the UART tx pin to a UART to USB converter, but this would mean I would have to buy an additional piece of hardware to do this.
I am wondering is there anyway that I can send data to my PC using the SWDIO pin and the chinese st linker v2? Or do I need to buy an external device so that I can send it using UART tx pin?

that seems to be exactly the description of what an STLinkv2 is for? I mean, you must also connect the SWCLK signal, but the point of a debugger interface like the STLink is that you can do exactly what you describe.

You should clarify term "transmit data to my PC". In general, St-link is debugger and when you are debugging your program, you can read values of variables, arrays, memories etc. (Debugger technicaly transmit data to PC). If you are looking only for "classic way" in style MCU->USB_UART_Bridge->Virtual_COMport, then it is not possible... as far as i know chinese St-link clones.

If you're running newlib you can switch in specs for so-called semi-hosting: --specs=rdimon.specs.
Basically what semi-hosting does is it provides you a stdout on your microcontroller via clever tricks using breakpoints, redirecting the output to your host (i.e., openocd or whatever environment you are in). So you can use printf() on the micro and see the output on your computer.

The STM32F030K6T6 uses a Cortex-M0 CPU.
KAN286 - Using ST-Link/V2 and MDK 5 with Discovery/Nucleo Boards
Keil Application Note 286 has:

23) printf for STM32F0 Cortex-M0: Uses Event Recorder and CoreSight DAP:
Event Recorder is a new Vision feature that can be used to instrument your code. Keil RTX5 and Middleware is already instrumented with Event Recorder. Event Recorder can provide a printf utility using the DAP read/write abilities of the Debug Access Port. A UART is not used. This can be used with STM32F0 Cortex-M0 parts as well as any STM32F processor. This is the same technology used in Watch, Memory and Peripheral windows. This method can also be used with any Cortex-M processor. It does not use SWV as does the method on page 14.

Where the Debug Access Port (DAP) allows reads and writes to your target while the program is running through the JTAG or SWD ports. I.e. the hardware should allow a printf utility without needing to use a UART.
Whereas Serial Wire Viewer (SWV) is supported on Corex-M3, M4 and M7 CPUs.
The question doesn't mention which development IDE is in use. The above Keil application note was written for ARM® Keil™ MDK toolkit featuring the IDE μVision®.
The STM32F030K6T6 has 32 Kbyte of Flash memory. The application note indicates the device will be supported by the free version of the software:

Keil MDK-Lite™ is a free evaluation version that limits code size to 32 Kbytes.

